# How to bypass website login via mql4 to get data

Tags: authentication, web, webrequest, mql4, metatrader4

How can I extract data from a website that is protected with a login and password via mql4?

I have the login credentials so this is not about hacking. I can get the html for any website but if a website has a login I can't get passed it.

I don't even know if login to a website is possible with mql4.

Anyone knows how to do this (if possible) ?

Many thanks

Comment: There are many different ways websites handle logins, much more information is required to provide an answer. In general it may be easier to write a dll to do the the work which MetaTrader can reference.

Comment: I am not sure how the server handles the login but this is the code for the login button: <div class="form-group rem35 pt-0">
        <input class="btn btn primary btn-block p-2 mt-3" onclick="(function() {  localStorage.clear(); localStorage.setItem('Refreshed', true);})()" style="color: #000000 !important;  font-weight: bold;" type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>